# How to get my simple hangman game to repeat

Tags: c++

Sorry if this is obvious, I'm new to coding.

Whenever the game ends and I type "y" to play again it displays what is already on the screen over and over again. I know that this is because whenever I type "y" it runs the active game instead of restarting, my question is, how do I get it to restart?

This is specifically about void playgame() and int main().

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string correcans = "coding";
std::string placeholder = "------";
std::string wrongans = "";
int amountguess = 6;



void title()
{
    std::cout << "##########################################" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "#                HANGMAN                 #" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "##########################################\n" << std::endl;
}

void hangdraw(int amountguess)
{
    if (amountguess == 6)
    {
        std::cout << " |-----------------|" << std::endl;
        std::cout << " |                 " << std::endl;
        std::cout << " |" << std::endl;
        std::cout << " |" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "_|__________________" << std::endl;
    }
    else if(amountguess == 5)
    {
        std::cout << " |-----------------|" << std::endl;
        std::cout << " |                 0" << std::endl;
        std::cout << " |                 " << std::endl;
        std::cout << " |" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "_|__________________" << std::endl;
    }
    else if (amountguess == 4)
    {
        std::cout << " |-----------------|" << std::endl;
        std::cout << " |                 0" << std::endl;
        std::cout << " |                 |" << std::endl;
        std::cout << " |                  " << std::endl;
        std::cout << "_|__________________" << std::endl;
    }
    else if (amountguess == 3)
    {
        std::cout << " |-----------------|" << std::endl;
        std::cout << " |                 0" << std::endl;
        std::cout << " |                 |" << std::endl;
        std::cout << " |                /" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "_|__________________" << std::endl;
    }
    else if (amountguess == 2)
    {
        std::cout << " |-----------------|" << std::endl;
        std::cout << " |                 0" << std::endl;
        std::cout << " |                 |" << std::endl;
        std::cout << " |                / \\" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "_|__________________" << std::endl;
    }
    else if (amountguess == 1)
    {
        std::cout << " |-----------------|" << std::endl;
        std::cout << " |                 0 /" << std::endl;
        std::cout << " |                 |" << std::endl;
        std::cout << " |                / \\" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "_|__________________" << std::endl;
    }
    else if (amountguess == 0)
    {
        std::cout << " |-----------------|" << std::endl;
        std::cout << " |               \\ 0 /" << std::endl;
        std::cout << " |                 |" << std::endl;
        std::cout << " |                / \\" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "_|__________________" << std::endl;
    }

}

void guessdisplay()
{
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << placeholder; 
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "\n------------------------------------------" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "|              Wrong Letters             |";
    std::cout << "\n------------------------------------------" << std::endl;

    std::cout << wrongans;

    std::cout << "\n------------------------------------------" << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Guesses Left: " << amountguess << std::endl;
}

char input()
{
    std::cout << "Guess Letter: ";
    char letter;

    std::cin >> letter;

    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore();

    return letter;
}

void guess(char letter)
{
    bool sameletter = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < placeholder.size(); i++)
    {
        if (correcans[i] == letter)
        {
            placeholder[i] = correcans[i];
            sameletter = true;
        }
    }

    if (sameletter == false)
    {
        amountguess -= 1;
        wrongans += letter;
    }
}

void winorlose()
{
    title();
    hangdraw(amountguess);
    guessdisplay();

    if (placeholder == correcans)
    {
        std::cout << "\n------------------------------------------" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "|                  YOU WIN!!!            |";
        std::cout << "\n------------------------------------------" << std::endl;
    }

    else
    {
        std::cout << "\n------------------------------------------" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "|                YOU LOSE!!!             |";
        std::cout << "\n------------------------------------------" << std::endl;
    }
}

void playgame()
{
    while (placeholder != correcans && amountguess > 0)
    {
        title();
        hangdraw(amountguess);
        guessdisplay();
        char letter = input();
        guess(letter);
        system("cls");
    }

    winorlose();

}

int main()
{
    bool isRunning = true;

    while (isRunning)
    {
        playgame();

        std::cout << "Would you like to play again (y/n)? ";

        char userChoice;
        std::cin >> userChoice;

        if (userChoice == 'y' || userChoice == 'Y')
        {
            isRunning = true;
        }
        else
        {
            isRunning = false;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: if you need help with code you need to post the code, a [mcve]. The code you did post does not display anything on the screen because it does not compile.

Comment: When one game end, you need to reset all your variables and all state of the game, starting over from its initial game-state. Perhaps create a function that does this reset and initialization, and call it before you call `playgame()`?

Comment: If you had not used global variables it'd probably be obvious. Create a `Game` class which stores the state of the game. Make `playgame()` a member function in that class. Instantiate a `Game` inside the `while (isRunning)` loop. [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/W8s73GEKn)

Comment: Put all your game code and data in a class (Hangman) and start a new object in the loop. e.g. `Hangman game(new_word); game->play();` instead of `playgame()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just need to reset variables after play

use this in int main() method

```
if (userChoice == 'y' || userChoice == 'Y')
        {
            placeholder = "------";
wrongans = "";
amountguess = 6;
            isRunning = true;
        }
        else
        {
            isRunning = false;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That was so simple lol